# Replacing keyboard USB-A cable with a USB-C female connector

Tags: usb, grounding, usb-c

I have a keyboard with a long non-detachable USB-A cable that I would like to replace with a USB-C female connector. My end goal is being able to detach the keyboard like a portable device and use it with any USB-C cable.

The original cable has a standard USB-A male plug on one side and 5-pin JST connector and O-ring on the other side. It contains 4 standard USB 2.0 wires (D+/D- and V+/V-) and one extra wire that is connected to the shielding/case of the actual USB-A plug. The pinout on the keyboard side is as follows:

[image: Keyboard PCB connectors]

I have a new cable with the same 5-pin JST connector and O-ring pinout, but with a USB-C female connector on the other side. I am going to open a hole in keyboard's casing in order to have this USB-C connector be reachable in order to plug a standard USB-C cable in it.

USB-C has many pins but the breakout board that I am using has the required 4 USB 2.0 pins I need apart the Shield pin. It is exactly that pin I have issues with since the original cable had a whole separate wire running from one side of the cable to the other and standard USB cables do not have this wire. So even if I connected a wire directly to the shielding/case of the USB-C connector, the case itself is not connected through the cable to the other side.

[image: USB-C female breakout board]

I have read through many articles but could not find a definitive answer on how to connect the Shield pin. These are the possibilities:

1. Do not connect Shield to anything (I feel like this is a bad idea)
2. Connect Shield to GND (V-) through a resistor, capacitor or ferrite bead (I want to do this, but am not sure if its safe)
3. Connect Shield directly to GND (V-) (also feels like a bad idea)

I would really appreciate some directions on how to do this as I do not want the keyboard to get damaged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connect shield to the body of the connector. That's literally what the shield is in such a cable.

If it's not exposed on the breakoutboard, you may be able to solder it to the shroud of the connector. Note that this is a bit risky, as you may melt the plastics if not careful.

If it's not exposed and you don't want to solder, you will *probably* be fine without shielding. The keyboard uses USB1, which has far lower bandwidth than USB2/3, so it will *probably* work fine without shield connected at both ends. It's unlikely to break anything.

Comment: Well I just went and checked to see if a random cable I have laying around had connected shrouds, and to my surprise they were. I just soldered the shield wire to the shroud of the USB-C connector like you said and the keyboard is perfectly working.

Comment: It should be, if the cable is according to USB specs. But for USB1 signals, it will probably work without any screen as well :)